# Match Pattern against File directly in Python?

Tags: python, regex, io

If I want to lazy read in python, I can keep a counter and read in chunks

```
i = 0
while len(str) == 1024:
    str = file.read(1024)
    pattern.match(str, i)
    i = i + len(str)
```

But if my pattern is `'\n{2000}'`, then the pattern will never be able to match, even if my file is 5000 empty lines. In fact, any greedy regex may have incorrect results when applied to externally-buffered input.

Is there a way to get `pattern.match` to match against a file object instead of a string? If not, what should I do to be sure my greedy regex matches accurately without potentially reading the entire file into memory at once? (the alternative being to use `seek` and `tell` instead).

Comment: I'd shell out to `grep` in this case.

Comment: You have only one way out: `file.read()`

Comment: @kindall in that case grep becomes a dependency, what's the best way to ensure that dependency is met?